Can you watch the sunset from Uvita Beach, Costa Rica?
I have read in several travel guides how beautiful the sunsets can be over the sea in Uvita.
The beach is within the Marino Ballena National Park, which, according to the official website, closes at 4pm.
Can you watch the sunset from Uvita beach, or is the whole beach closed off and inaccessible after the park closes?

Have you asked this question of the Costa Rica national Park staff ?

What happens at 4pm if you are already on the beach?

The same website (but in Spanish) here, says 7AM to 6PM, not 4PM.  Also Sunset will always pretty well be before 6PM

Sunset is before 6pm, @PeterM? What time of year? I don't know if Costa Rica is UTC-5 or -6, but I'm -5 and sunset is ~9pm for me today. Granted, in late December it's more like 5-6pm. Unless Punta Uvita is very tall (blocking the sun early) sunset shouldn't be that late (google maps says Punta Uvita is not tall at all and shouldn't impede the Westerly view from Playa Uvita at all).

@FreeMan Costa Rica is near the equator, so sunrise and sunset are different from higher latitudes.  See here for June. And here for December

@FreeMan its the lattitude that matters, not the time zone (longitude). Near the equator, day/night are about the same length. The suns sets very quickly too because it descends vertically, not at an angle as in more northern/southern lattitudes.

@WeatherVane it’s actually both the latitude and the offset between the time zone and actual solar time which matter. Uvita Beach is 6.24 degrees East of its time zone centreline, so the sun rises/sets nearly 25 minutes before the nominal time for that latitude, which explains why, even when the sun is visible slightly more than 12 hours in a day (in the summer), sunrise is before 6 pm.

On the other hand, it might be useful to check tide times: from what can be seen on the satellite view on Google Maps (looking at the limit between wet and dry sand), at high tide there is probably not much of the beach which isn't under water.

Ah, that makes sense, thanks @all. I'm used to more northern latitudes and hadn't thought about that.

There is access to the beach from town and you can see the sunset from there -- from someone who has been and has seen the sunset from that beach. Don't worry, pura vida.
